# Cannot push a viewController inside a ViewDidload method in another Viewcontroller

Tags: ios7, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller, viewdidload

I want to do something like this in my iOS application.

I alredy have a splash screen and a login screen,, After the Splashviewcontroller it displays the LoginViewcontroller.

Im checking some conditions inside the `ViewDidload`and in a particular condition I want to push to an another viewcontroller. This is working in ios 5,and 6 but in ios 7 this is not loading when this condition is true.

This is my code

```
-(void)viewDidLoad 
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

 self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden=YES;
 mutArrLoggedUsrarray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
 newuser=[NEWLoginUSER sharedManager];
 nws=[NEWWebservice sharedManager];
 alertObject=[AlertsString sharedManager];
 alert=[CreateProgressAlert sharedManager];
 NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

 NSString *strLogStatus=[defaults objectForKey:@"LOGWAY"];

 if ([strLogStatus isEqualToString:@"EMAIL"]) {

    phoneLiginView.hidden=YES;
    emailLoginView.hidden=NO;
    isCurrentViewPhone=NO;
    KeychainItemWrapper *keychainItemPHONE = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"PHONENO" accessGroup:nil];
    NSString *userTypedEmail=[keychainItemPHONE objectForKey:(__bridge id)(kSecAttrAccount)];
    NSString *userTypedPassword=[keychainItemPHONE objectForKey:(__bridge id)(kSecValueData)];
    newuser.strEmail=userTypedEmail;

    TxtEmail.text=newuser.strEmail;
   // [changeBoxbtn setTitle:@"LOGIN WITH PHONE NUMBER" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    changeBoxbtn.hidden=YES;

}
else if([strLogStatus isEqualToString:@"PHONE"])
{
    txtUsrname.text=[newuser.strPhoneNum stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+94" withString:@""];


    isCurrentViewPhone=YES;
    //[changeBoxbtn setTitle:@"LOGIN WITH EMAIL ID" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    changeBoxbtn.hidden=YES;

}
else{
    isCurrentViewPhone=YES;

    RegisterViewController *regvieww=[[RegisterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RegisterViewController" bundle:nil];


    [regvieww.view addSubview:regvieww.viewVerify];
    [regvieww.view addSubview:regvieww.viewTop];

    [regvieww.view addSubview:regvieww.regViaEmailView];
    [regvieww.view addSubview:regvieww.selectorView];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:regvieww animated:YES];

}



    originalCenter=self.view.center;
    if ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height==480) {
       originalCenter.y=240;
    }

}
```

Can u tell me what is the problem with this. And how to solve this

Comment: I set that inside this else part. Please check and tell me

Comment: Don't push another viewcontroller in ViewDidLoad. Try using ViewDidAppear Method.

Comment: but its going to show the first vwcontroller and then goes to the second one,,, I want to awoide the displaying that first vwcontroller. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Then you may like to try using concept of adding ChildViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your conditions to your AppDelegate in the method:
didFinishLaunching

And set the first viewController accordingly.

You can also try moving your code from viewDidLoad to viewWillAppear.

Pushing a viewController animated in viewDidLoad won't work.